# What is this function

Tags: integer-partitions

Let $\left(\delta_{i,j}\right)_{5\times5}$ be a 
matrix with $\delta_{i,i}=1$ and $\delta_{i,j}=\delta_{j,i}=1$ or
$0$ when $i\ne j$ and $\delta_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{5}\delta_{i,j}$.
Let 
$$
f(k):=\max_{\delta_{1}+\delta_{2}+\delta_{3}+\delta_{4}+\delta_{5}=k}\delta_{1}\delta_{2}\delta_{3}\delta_{4}\delta_{5}
$$
for $5\le k\le25$, then what is the combinatorial expression
of $f(k)$ as a function of $k$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 0):

Your $\delta_i$ is just how many of $1..5$ are equal to $i$, i.e., 1 if $1 \le i \le 5$. The maximum of the products of $\delta_i$ is thus one (if all 5 give one), and that can happen only if their sum is 5 (five of those can't ever sum more than 5). Thus $f(n) = \delta_{n, 5}$.

Comment: It should be minimum in the definition of f(k), and had been corrected before you posted your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ever if for maximum, isn't the product with more 1's  off the diagonal larger?

Comment: What you posted does not answer the question. Could you please remove it? Thanks.